# Proof of Levy-Khintchine formula on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

This is a loaded question. I made another post in this community requesting guidance for finding a good quality proof of the Levy-Khintchine formula on $\mathbb{R}$. I got a few suggestions but sadly the books I was pointed to didn't contain the proof I need (either $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is too complicated for my level or they didn't contain the proof at all). Now im asking if anyone has the good will to derive the formula here on mathematics stack exchange. I know it's long but I believe it could help many people with the understanding of said formula.

The probability measure $\mu$ on the real line is infinitely divisible with characteristic exponent $\Phi$ if and only if there exists a triple $(a, \sigma, \Pi)$, where $a, \sigma \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\Pi$ is a measure on $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ satisfying $\int_{\mathbb{R}}1 \wedge x^2 \Pi(dx)\leq \infty$, such that for every $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, the following holds:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{i\theta x} \mu(dx) = e^{-\Phi(\theta)},\ \text{for} \ \theta \in \mathbb{R},
$$
and
$$
\Phi(\theta) = i a \theta + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\theta^2 + \int_{\mathbb{R}}(1 - e^{i\theta x} + i\theta x 1_{(|x|<1)})\Pi(dx).
$$
Furthermore, the triple $(a, \sigma, \Pi)$ is uniquely determined.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is the proof for $\mathbb{R}^n$ beyond your level?

Comment: Im an undergraduate mathematics student, and have been through  a  measure theoretic probability course, and a stochastic processes course. So far have not done much outside $\mathbb{R}$, im really interested in probability theory so for my bsc. thesis project i chose to present Levy processes on $\mathbb{R}$, since they go hand in hand with infinitely divisible distributions I would like to understand the derivation of this formula, but for example Sato's book is just to advanced for my current understanding. I hope to one day think this is trivial but unitl then I could use some help.

Comment: I guess [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.00251.pdf) contains a relatively simple proof under the assumption $\int_{\mathbb{R}} x^2 \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x) < \infty$, see pages 22--23.